# Turn multi-cell table into one cell table

Tags: css

I've googled a bit to find the solution for transforming a multi-cell table into one cell table, using css (media) **DYNAMICALLY!**. I found a solution which is not good, because it's mixing results. 
This is what I am trying to do...

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

RESULT:

One cell table: Jill,Smith,50,Eve,Jackson,94

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill
    Smith
    50
    Eve
    Jackson
    94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the above is what you are trying to do, then you can't. CSS can not alter your HTML code this way.

```
 <table style="width:200px">
  <tr style="width:100px; position:absolute">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="width:100px; left:100px; position:absolute">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now this may LOOK like it is one cell, since the two rows are inline thanks to the `absolute` positioning (`display:inline-block` doesn't work). I made it simple. You can use percentages, to make it somewhat more flexible, but I really DO NOT RECOMMEND you to go this way.

I think your issue, whatever it may be, should be solved differently, then by merging cells.